# AJAX won't transfer variable to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to transfer input from Javascript to PHP with AJAX but the input will not transfer.
Here is my JS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div{border:solid;}
div{background-color:blue;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="comments"> </div>
<br>
<span> Comment: </span> <input id="comment"> <button onclick="getInput()"> Submit Comment </button>

<script>
function getInput(){
    var input = document.getElementById("comment").value;
    addComment(input);
}
function addComment(input){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET","chatroom.php?i="+input,false);
    request.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP Code:

```
<?php
$input = $_REQUEST["i"];
file_get_contents("chatext.txt",$input);

?>
```

The PHP code is executed, but the variable is not transferred.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `file_get_contents()`? Its second parameter is related to the include path, not any string input. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: did you mean `file_put_contents`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: And have you inspected the browser's Network console while the XHR is executed? Do you see the query string added there?  At a minimum, you need to use `escape(input)` to urlencode the value sent with `i`.

Comment: You're thinking of `file_put_contents()` not `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: My mistake, thanks so much! Please put it in the form of an answer to close the question properly.

Comment: That was it? It works with `file_put_contents()` otherwise?

Comment: @tester you go ahead with the answer.

Comment: Apparently, there was also a slight problem with my servers.

Comment: I don't want to answer my own question, somebody please just answer it.

Comment: btw you do not "transfer input from js to php", you make and HTTP request from the client to the server - properly understanding that you are dealing w/ HTTP protocol solves 99% of the issues : ))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you mean `file_put_contents("chatext.txt", $input)`?

[php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)